# Combo no Pysimplegui

Tags: python, pysimplegui

Tenho um projeto onde preciso colocar uma lista em um Combo no `PySimpleGui`.  Eu já criei a lista em uma função e quando chamo essa função, a lista é impressa, porém não vai para o `Combo`.  Abaixo o código:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

from Empresas import *

def tela_inicial():
    sg.theme('Default1')

    coluna1 = [
            [sg.Text('Empresa', font='arial 12')],
            [sg.Text('Conta', font='arial 12')],
            [sg.Text('Mês', font='arial 12')]
    ]

    coluna2 = [
            [sg.Combo([empresa()], size=(15, 30), font='Arial 12', key='Empresas')],
            [sg.Input(font='arial 12', key='Conta', size=(30, 20))],
            [sg.Input(font='arial 12', key='Mês', size=(30, 20))]
    ]

    layout = [
            [sg.Text('Texto', font='arial 20 bold')],
            [sg.Column(coluna1), sg.Column(coluna2)],
            [sg.Multiline(size=(60, 100))],
            [sg.Text('PW4©', pad=(0, (35, 0)))]

    ]
    telaprin = sg.Window('Análise', element_justification='left', element_padding=(0, 10),
                            layout=layout, size=(900, 600), finalize=True)
```

Quando executo ele retorna uma lista vazia no `Combo`.

Comment: Qual é o retorno de `empresa()` em `sg.Combo([empresa()], ...)`?

Comment: O retorno dessa função é uma lista com nome de empresas.



Quando coloco essa função no sg.combo, que pede uma lista, ele aparece como vazia....

Answer (score 0):

Rodei o seu código na minha máquina e percebi que está faltando o comando para inicializar a janela, ou seja, um return na sua função `telaPython` e um `while True` para deixar a janela ativa. O motivo para não aparecer a lista no seu `sg.combo` se dá pelo fator que a lista está vazia e mesmo se a sua lista possuindo valores, o seu `sg.combo,` vai entender que se trata de uma lista dentro de uma lista e não vai exibir valores sequencialmente na vertical.
Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Solução

Imaginamos que temos dois arquivos um que contém a lista (**dados.py**) e outra que seria o arquivo da sua interface **pysimplegui.py**

**dados.py**

```
def  empresas():
    return ['Itaú', 'Bradesco', 'Santander']
```

**pysimplegui.py** repare que estou inicializando a tela e passando a função `empresas` no `sg.combo` sem precisar de colocar dentro de uma lista

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from dados import *


def tela_inicial():
    sg.theme("Default1")

    coluna1 = [
        [sg.Text("Empresa", font="arial 12")],
        [sg.Text("Conta", font="arial 12")],
        [sg.Text("Mês", font="arial 12")],
    ]

    coluna2 = [
        [sg.Combo(empresas(), size=(15, 30), font="Arial 12", key="Empresas")],
        [sg.Input(font="arial 12", key="Conta", size=(30, 20))],
        [sg.Input(font="arial 12", key="Mês", size=(30, 20))],
    ]

    layout = [
        [sg.Text("Texto", font="arial 20 bold")],
        [sg.Column(coluna1), sg.Column(coluna2)],
        [sg.Multiline(size=(60, 100))],
        [sg.Text("PW4©", pad=(0, (35, 0)))],
    ]

    telaprin = sg.Window(
        "Análise",
        element_justification="left",
        element_padding=(0, 10),
        layout=layout,
        size=(900, 600),
        finalize=True,
    )

    # retornando a interface
    return telaprin


# inicializando a interface
janela = tela_inicial()

# mantendo a tela ativa, caso você for fechar o while é interrompido
while True:
    window, event, values = sg.read_all_windows()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
```

**Resultado** abrindo a janela e com o sg.combo exibindo a lista

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]